# While true loop request infinitely looping

Tags: shell

I've set up a while loop that is supposed to ask the user to type a number between 0 and 10, then give various responses based on their input. However, when executing the program, if anything not 0, 5, or 10 is typed, it infinitely loops one of the below responses, instead of displaying it once.

```
INPUTMOD=0
echo "Please enter a number from 0-10, inclusive"
read INPUTMOD

while true
do
    if [ "$INPUTMOD" -lt 0 ] || [ "$INPUTMOD" -gt 10 ]; then
        echo "Please enter a number between 0 and 10, inclusive"
    elif [ "$INPUTMOD" -eq 0 ] || [ "$INPUTMOD" -eq 5 ] || [ "$INPUTMOD" -eq 10 ]; then
        echo "Your input is congruent with _ mod 5 = 0. Congratulations!"
        break
    else
        echo "Please enter a number between 0 and 10, inclusive."
    fi
done
```

the overall objective of this loop is to continuously prompt the user for a number between 0 and 10, until they type 0, 5, or 10 (for input mod 5 = 0). when a non-numerical key is pressed, it will infinitely prompt the user to type a correct number.

Any and all help regarding this is much appreciated!

EDIT: the while true, if else, lt, and gt are all necessary for this, as instructed by my professor.

Comment: Side note: As this seems to be a learning assignment you are most probably asked to compute the modulo rather than enumerating the congruent options.

Comment: Note that there are no numbers that are both less than 0 and greater than 10, so the first condition never fires.

Comment: This particular question says "Using a while true loop request, accept and display data until it ends on input mod 5 = 0 using -lt and -gt comparison commands". I interpretted it as inputting numbers to check if it's mod 5 = 0, where it then breaks the loop if true, but continuously prompts if false. I'm still relatively new to shell, so am I actually doing this entire question wrong?

Comment: Can't tell you, but it would be possible to calculate the modulo using subtraction and comparison. So while x is greater than (or equal to) 5 subtract 5, whatever remains is by definition the result of the modulo.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing some logic:

```
if [ "$INPUTMOD" -lt 0 ] && [ "$INPUTMOD" -gt 10 ]; then
```

should be

```
if [ "$INPUTMOD" -lt 0 ] || [ "$INPUTMOD" -gt 10 ]; then
```

Because no number can be less than 0 AND greater than 10 the same time.
And

```
elif [ "$INPUTMOD" -eq 0 ] || [ "$INPUTMOD" -eq 5 ] [ "$INPUTMOD" -eq 10 ]; then
```

is incomplete. What exactly is missing you'll sure find out.. ;)

And then: Your while loop is expected to run forever. Wouldn't you say it's good to not only ask for a new number but also to accept one?

Comment: Whoops. You got me on the and/or operators and I adjusted it, but the program is still infinitely looping if a number greater than 10 is typed. Not sure how exactly I'd go about fixing that.

Oh yeah, and for the elif, there's a 2nd or operator, I just forgot to type it there. Fixed.

Comment: @Ibrahim see my edit.. Think what happens when the loop is rerun the first time. When will the user interaction happen and allow for a new number?

Comment: edit: i just used read INPUTMOD and it appears to have done the trick. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If condition is wrong then you have to ask for the number,

just change your code something like this,

add following statement before `done` statement,

```
read INPUTMOD
```

and that's it.

So now it won't ask continuously for a number,
It will ask for one time and wait for your input